# Synchronizing threads according to a specific property of monitor object in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

My program imitating work on a repository. 
The resource that must be synchronized is the array `cells` in a `Repository`object (used as monitor).
The threads (`RepoThread` class) are allowed to add or subtract values to/from the cell values of the array, but only when no other thread is doing the same thing on **the same cell**. `RepoThread`s do actions(add/subtract) simultaneously as long as they do that on different cells. 
Cells that are currently in process will be considered "busy" and their indexes will be stored in a HashMap.

I have these classes (:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
public class Repository {
    private int[] cells;
    private Set<Integer> busyCells;

    public Repository(int size, int initialValue) {

        busyCells = new HashSet<Integer>();

        cells = new int[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            cells[i] = initialValue;
    }

    public synchronized void add(int index, int amount, int threadId) {
        while (busyCells.contains((Integer) index)) { // cell is busy
            try {
                System.out.println("thread" + threadId
                        + "will wait to ADD on cell" + index
                        + ", busy cells:" + busyCells);
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        // cell is not busy now
        busyCells.add(index);

        cells[index] = cells[index] + amount;
        busyCells.remove((Integer) index);
        System.out.println("Thread n." + threadId
                + " just ADDED " + amount
                + " to cell " + index
                + ", new amount=" + cells[index]
                + ", busy cells: " + busyCells);

        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void remove(int index, int amount, int threadID) {
        while (busyCells.contains((Integer) index)) {
            System.out.println("thread n." + threadID
                    + " tried to remove " + amount
                    + " from cell " + index + ""
                    + " but the amount is " + cells[index]
                    + "busy cells:" + busyCells);
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("interrupted");
            }
        }
        busyCells.add(index);
        cells[index] = cells[index] - amount;
        busyCells.remove((Integer) index);
        System.out.println("thread n." + threadID
                + " just REMOVED " + amount
                + " from cell " + index + ","
                + " new amount is " + cells[index]
                + ", busy cells: " + busyCells);

        notifyAll();

    }

    public int size() {
        return cells.length;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RepoThread extends Thread {
    Repository mon;
    int id;
    int addOrRemove;
    int index;
    int amount;

    public RepoThread(Repository mon, int id, int addOrRemove, int index, int amount) {
        this.mon = mon;
        this.id = id;
        this.addOrRemove = addOrRemove;
        this.index = index;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (addOrRemove == 1) {
            mon.add(index, amount,id);
        }else if(addOrRemove==2){
            mon.remove(index, amount, id);
        }else{
            System.out.println("unknown operation requested");
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class TestRepository {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Repository repo = new Repository(10, 5);
        RepoThread remover1 = new RepoThread(repo, 1, 2, 5, 8);
        remover1.start();
        RepoThread remover2 = new RepoThread(repo, 2, 2, 5, 4);
        remover2.start();
        RepoThread adder1 =   new RepoThread(repo, 3, 1, 5, 4);
        adder1.start();
        RepoThread adder2 =   new RepoThread(repo, 4, 1, 5, 2);
        adder2.start();
        RepoThread adder3 =   new RepoThread(repo, 5, 1, 7, 4);
        adder3.start();
        RepoThread adder4 =   new RepoThread(repo, 6, 1, 5, 4);
        adder4.start();

    }
}
```

My problem is that it seems that no collisions occur because my `add` and `remove` methods are `synchronized`. This means that when any thread is doing add or remove the `Repository` object is locked and no other thread can access the array anyway since the whole object is locked and not just the busy cell.

What change am I supposed to make so the threads will be able to do whatever they want on Repository object as long as they are doing it on a non-busy cell of `cells` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to lock more precisely on Cell directly, right? If so...

One option could be to replace synchronize by synchronize block on cell object itself (if you create an array of Cell object - meaning you create a Cell class -).

```
// Example
Cell [] cells = new Cell[nb];
// initialize the array as you need

// later on, in remove or add
synchronize (cells[i]) {
   // your stuff
}
```

Another option could be to lock through an array of ReentrantLock, one per cell.

```
ReentrantLock [] locks = new ReentrantLock[nb];
// fill the array of ReentranLock, one per cell

locks[cellRank].lock();
try {
   // your stuff
} finally {
  lock[cellRank].unlock();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Anyway to do it with synchronized blocks and waits without locks?

Comment: If you use synchronize blocks (1rst possibility), you can still wait on cells[i] with `cells[i].wait()` and wakeup them with `cells[i].notifyAll()`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: the cells are primitive type.. your second suggestion worked form me. Thanks!